# Adding rows breaks datatable in Django

Tags: django, datatables, django-templates

I have a datatable in Django that functions fine when hardcoded, but when I add my Django template tags it breaks. The inspect on the page says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined` in jquery.datatables.min.js

This only happens when I have more than one user in the table, or try to add a column in the table with django. Since I will be using multiple datatables in my project, I need to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The datatable JS code I'm using comes from a template, and I'm not sure if the error is in the template code or in my Django template code. So please excuse the long code blocks.

employees.html (django template):

```
<div class="card-body collapse in">
                    <div class="card-block card-dashboard">
                        <button id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 js-create-employee"><i class="ft-plus"></i>&nbsp; Add New Employee</button>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Roles</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Mobile Contact</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                {% for profile in user_profile_list %}
                                    <tr>
                                    {% if not profile.user.is_superuser %}
                                        <td><a href="{% url 'dispatch:profile_detail' pk=profile.user_id %}">{{ profile.user.get_full_name }}</a></td>
                                        <td>{{ profile.user.username }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            {% for g in profile.user.groups.all %}
                                               <div class="tag tag-default">{{ g.name|split:'_'|title }}</div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{ profile.user.email }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ profile.mobile_phone }}</td>
                                        <td><a href="#" alt="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" alt="Assign"><i class="fa fa-link"></i><a/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" alt="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><a/></td>

                                        {% endif %}
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Roles</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Mobile Contact</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Datatable instantiation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/****************************************
*       js of zero configuration        *
****************************************/

$('.zero-configuration').DataTable();
});
```

Jquery.datatables.min.js and dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js are also used, but those come stock from bootstrap 4. I'm not going to add them here unless needed, and they are minified anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues occurs only when data is not available for the table  or  tags.

You have conditions in template using django templatestag So the number of every `<td>` element in your table that is a child of a `<tr>` element doesn't match the number of `<th>` elements that are a child of the  element.
Please make sure you have same number of `<td>` tag in `<tbody>` tag.

**EDIT:**

Maybe  {% if not profile.user.is_superuser %} this condition creating this issue. If user is superuser then no `<td>` tag will create that will not match same number of `<th>` in `<thead>`

Comment: I understand that, but the data is the same for each user. So why does it have issues?

Comment: If user is superuser then {% if not profile.user.is_superuser %} this condition can create that issue. number of <th> will not with <td>

Comment: The superuser code works if I only have one additional user. It's when I add a second non-superuser to the users that the table breaks

Comment: Can you add html output code in question that will help to understand structure of table?

Comment: Removed the super user check, and it works. But I can't figure out why it works with one non-superuser and not more than one. But your answer was correct, and I marked it. Thanks! Really appreciate it!